# How to keep values of variables in php when clicking on an href?

Tags: php, mysqli

For a website that I am developing for my new business I have created a way for customers to create an account an login. When the customer has logged in there is a calendar that I made in PHP that connects to SQL to show available times for my service. At the top of my code for the web page it validates the account which is taken from a form on a previous screen

```
<?php

include 'DB_connect.php';

$PHONE = $_POST['phone'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = '$PHONE' AND pass = '$PASSWORD';";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!isset($check)) {
    echo 'Incorrect Username/Password Combination';
    exit();
}
?>
```

On the calendar, when you switch between the months, I created an href to print out the calendar in php like so

```
<h4><a href="?ym=<?php echo $prev;?>">&lt;</a><?php echo $html_title; ?><a href="?ym=<?php echo $next; ?>">&gt;</a></h4>
```

But when switching to the previous and next month, it reruns the code at the top checking the login for the user it logs them out because there is no value for the

```
$PHONE = $_POST['phone'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];
```

so it ends up logging the user out when trying to switch between months on my calendar. 
What do I need to do so that the user stays logged in while switching between months? Is there a way to change the phone and password variables to constants once the user is logged in or something? I have been stuck on this for days and havent been able to figure this out. PLZ HELP!

Comment: Directly passing user input into SQL queries is a huge risk; this is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: you let them login first then save it in session so it persists. then once they are authenticated, your business logic can go on as normal

Comment: and well just like the comment above, your code is vulnerable to sql injection plus you're saving the password naked

Comment: @Kevin what code would I need to write to save it in session and where would I put it?

Comment: You should store the userid in a session variable. Not the password/phone, then check if that value is set.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). You should start a session after verifying the user's credentials. You can then store whatever user information you need in the session using the `$_SESSION` super global.

On subsequent interactions, you check that the session is valid rather than revalidating the user credentials.

You should also address the SQL injection vulnerability and properly hash passwords in your database.

Login Form POST:

```
<?php
if(/*Verify user credentials*/){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
}
?>
```

Authenticated Page View:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    //Do authenticated actions
}
else{
    //User is not authenticated
}
?>
```

There are many other aspects to handling sessions that would be too in-depth to describe here. You would need to properly configure expiration for sessions and consider the storage mechanism, for instance. If you are running your application behind a load balancer, you will need a central session storage location(like a database or Redis). There are many other factors to consider with this.

Comment: thank you! this solved my problem and this is my first website that I have developed that I have created a login page that will be live. What would be the best thing for me to read and learn about how to address SQL injection?

Comment: @TannerHelms The short answer is to use prepared statements which let you specify parameters in the query. You prepare a statement and then bind the parameters to it and any input values will be escaped. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php OWASP has some general information on SQL injection that you may find helpful: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection